# Nesting Dijit.layout.BorderContainer in Dijit.form.Form

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

I have a small web app I wrote that has a Dijit.layout.BorderContainer nested within a Dijit.form.Form. The form controls are scattered about several ContentPanes within the BorderContainer, hence why the form is the parent to the entire container. This worked fine with Dojo 1.5, but when I switch to Dojo 1.6, the whole layout is messed up, with everything piled in a mess at the top of the page (using the Dijit 1.6 CSS works fine when I continue to use Dojo 1.5 -- it is when I flip the switch on the Dojo 1.6 library that things get messed up).

Any ideas on what the matter might be and how I can overcome it? I've tried taking everything out of my containers to ensure the content itself is not messing up the layout. It wasn't.

Comment: Playing around with this, I found that everything works OK if I use a local build of Dojo 1.7b1 instead of 1.6 off the CDN. I'm guessing that means there is a bug in 1.6. However, I'm not sure if the beta is lacking optimizations or the CDN has some special magic, but my web app with 1.7b1 takes about six to eight seconds to load (way up from near instantaneous loading of 1.5 or 1.6 over CDN). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the outer form widget to height: 100%, then the nested bordercontainer gets the right height.

Comment: Ah, yes. It turned out some fixed sizes were playing havoc with the whole thing. Thanks!